# "Menu" to "Close" Text Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

[image: Menu to Close Transition]

I came across a neat menu transition effect, where they replace the "menu" text with the "close" text, I found it on this site - simple.com. This happens on mobile. **As well as, I have a GIF of the effect above.** **I'm trying to replicate the same exact effect they have.**

**Does anybody know how I might do this?** I would like to do this using HTML, CSS, and Javascript/or jQuery.

I do not have any code to show. Due to a lack of knowledge in Javascript and jQuery. Therefore, I do not even know how to describe what's going on, and what effect/transition I'm looking for it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you know the website, and you want the same effect. You can simply inspect the element, copy its `html` and its `css`. Then watch what happens when you click the element to know what JS to apply.

This is literally copy-pasted from their source code, pretty simple(.com) if you ask me :).

```js
$(function() {
  $('.mobile-toggle').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.mobile-toggle {
  background: #0d97ff;
  border: 2px solid #0d97ff;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "CalibreBold", helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 34px;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 25px;
  position: relative;
  width: 85px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
  -ms-transition: background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
  transition: background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
}

.mobile-toggle.active {
  background: #fff;
  color: #0d97ff;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
  -ms-transition: background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
  transition: background 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
}

.mobile-toggle .toggle-labels {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 68px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
}

.mobile-toggle.active .toggle-labels {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-34px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-34px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-34px);
  transform: translateY(-34px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
  transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.49, 0.99, 0.54, 0.98);
}

.mobile-toggle .toggle-labels .menu {
  display: block;
  height: 34px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.mobile-toggle .toggle-labels .close {
  display: block;
  height: 34px;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="mobile-toggle">
  <span class="toggle-labels">
  <span class="menu">Menu</span>
    <span class="close">Close</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was going for! I was trying to find out how to find it in the inspect element section, but it looks like I may be able to figure it out with a bit of research.